# Send single String/not Object with Thymeleaf to Spring

Tags: string, spring, thymeleaf

I'm trying to send a single String to my Spring backend. I don't want to make an extra Object just for that string.

```
<form name="f" th:action="@{/restaurant_SaveLayout}" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" value="trdz234"/>
    <button type="submit"></button>
</form>
```

Spring tells me that I the RequestParam is not present.

```
@PostMapping("/restaurant_SaveLayout")
public String restaurant_SaveLayout (@RequestParam String circles) {
    return "restaurant_ShowArr";
}
```

I also don't want to send anything via GET.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed to set the name of the input.

```
<form name="f" th:action="@{/restaurant_SaveLayout}" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="circles" value="trdz234"/>
    <button type="submit"></button>
</form>
```